# What Regular Expression Can I Use To Find Simple Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string, which is the source of a regular expression:

```
"For example, I have (.*) string with (\.d+) special bits (but this is just an aside)."
```

Is there a way to extract the special parts of the regular expression?

In particular, I'm interested in the parts that will give back values when I call `string.match(expr);`

Comment: All parts could potentially give you values depending on what you match them against. If you are interested in capturing regex groups, can't you just use a regular expression to extract any parenthesized parts containing special characters like *, [, ], escape sequences like \s \w etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex can be complicated, but if you do a global regex with `([\.\\]([*a-z])\+?)`, it will capture your individual fields without including the parenthesis per your request. Demo code as put in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/gof44vj7/7/) fiddle is below as well.

```
var testString = 'For example, I have (.*) string with (.d+) special bits (but this is just an aside). (\\w+)';
var regex = /([\.\\]([*a-z])\+?)/gi;

var matches_array = testString.match(regex);

//Outputs the following: [".*", ".d+", "\w+"]
```

Comment: I hate to add scope creep... but could you include an example snippet of JavaScript that would result in the following value `["*", "d", "w"]` - which is almost what your updated example returns. I'm not an expert a capturing groups and these single-character(ish) results would be perfect for what I need.

Comment: @SteveFenton Oh, you mean with the outputted values?

Comment: Yes please - using `.match` or similar... your answer is really close as when I match using it I get `["(\\.*)","(\\d+)","(\\w+)"]` - which I *can* use if needs be.

Comment: @SteveFenton Here you go!

Comment: @SteveFenton Hah, I bet you actually want the demo, don't you? https://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/gof44vj7/4/ . Only thing is, I was unable to strip the parenthesis, you'll probably have to do a string manipulation of some sort to take those off if you need them to.

Comment: @SteveFenton https://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/gof44vj7/7/ - I fixed the regex. It now doesn't capture the parenthesis. I also modified the answer to your updated request here in the comments.

Comment: It should be noted that while this is a fine solution for the particular problem, it is not a generic solution for extracting group expressions from regular expression strings. It matches invalid sequences such as \g, \h etc and doesn't match a vast number of valid expressions. I doubt one can produce a sufficiently generic solution using regular expressions. Then again, that's what parsers are for.

Comment: @kliron The purpose of this wasn't to be a catch all solution. The idea was to give enough various elements of regex to give OP the answer he needed, but demonstrate enough of the various tools so that he can hopefully take something away from this and start doing more complex regex matching.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not powerful enough to recognize the language of matching parentheses.  (The formal proof uses the equivalence of regular expressions and finite state machines and the fact that there are infinitely many levels of nesting possible.)  Thus, matching the first `)` after each `(` would make `(\d+(\.d+)?)` return `(\d+(\.d+)` and matching the last `)` after each `(` would make `(\w+) (\w+)` match the entire string.

The correct way to do this is with recursion (which mathematical regular expressions do not allow, but actual implementations such as PCRE do).  You can also get a simple expression for non-nested parentheses.  Just be careful to parse escape characters: to be fully robust, `\(` and `\\\(` are special, but `\\(` is not.

Comment: PCRE is not mathematical regular expressions, it's more powerful. It includes recursion, for instance.

Comment: Yes, it has extensions.  As of last time I checked, though, it was not powerful enough to recognize the language of matched parentheses, so I thought bringing that up wouldn't be relevant.  But I’ll add a note.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the recursion operator does allow matching any kind of balanced expression.

Comment: @Barmar Corrected.  Thank you!